# jquery.Post() to a method with Task<ActionResult> callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Have searched around the site but no one has provided an actual answer to questions of this type.

I have a `jquery.post()` authentication to be sent to the backend for processing. This method will then redirect me to the home page showing that it is logged in.

This is my script.

```
$.post("Auth/SocialAuth", results,  function () { //having difficulty with this });
```

And the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SocialAuth(string userId, string authToken, string name) {

        string message;
        try{
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("id", userId);

            var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync<SocialAuthObject>("methodToInvoke", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, parameters); //Mobile Services Code

            Session["userId"] = result.id;
            Session["authToken"] = authToken;
            Session["username"] = name;


        }

        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message; 
            TempData["errMsg"] = message;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Auth");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Status", "Home");
   }
```

There are two problems. One of which is that the Session isn't actually instantiated with this. The second problem is that it doesn't Redirect to the Action like all other instances with `RedirectToAction("Status", "Home")` Even more strangely, when the page is debugged, the breakpoint at `SocialAuth` fires, and there weren't any exceptions fired by the server.

I suspect that it is the fact that I have not handled the callback for the `jquery.post()` method properly. But I would like to know if there are any other mistakes I have made.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, use a normal submit - using ajax is pointless in this situation.

Comment: Add the details of the functions which does the POST call also.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen for the response. 

As you might have guessed it is indeed an oAuth callback. Is there a way for me to submit to a site from an oAuth callback to the SocialAuth method in the backend without using my method? I am pretty green to Javascript myself and so would like suggestions.